# How to get image text position x,y using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, image-processing

ImageTextPosition

[image]

Hi all,

I want to search for a specific text on the image and draw a circle on that text and keep the circle on the text while zooming in or out.

In other words, how to get image text position x,y then draw a circle on the text and keep the circle on the text while zooming in or out.

Using pure C# preferred.
Please find the attached picture and let say want draw circle on the text "300".

I appreciated your help.

Comment: this is not a trivial task: basically what you want falls in the domain of OCR (Optical Character Recognition) and there are libraries like Tasseract https://github.com/tesseract-ocr that can help you solve this, but this problem is harder than it looks...

Comment: Thank you, if it's not simple then what I want is to draw a button on the map at a fxed position can't be changed if map zooming in or out using C#.

Comment: if you know the scaling factor you should be able to calculate the position and size where to draw that button

Comment: Can you recommend a link with this process steps?

Comment: you probably won't find a process that does exactly this... but ... it boils down to coordinate transformation based on a transformation matrix ... if you zoom in, your map is stretched which can be expressed as a matrix transform ... once you pan around on your map, that can be expressed as a matrix transform ... if you know the coordinates on the original map treat them as a vector. you can now apply all transformations that were applied to your map, to your vector and recieve the coordinates after the transformation... that's where you want to draw

Answer (score 0):

You need some external library for image processing like OpenCV.
Wrapper for .NET is called [EMGU](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)

Comment: Thank you, what I want is to draw a button on the map at a fixed position can't be changed if map zooming in or out using C#.